# convert greasemonkey wildcard to regex

Tags: javascript, regex, greasemonkey, wildcard

Is there a simple replace function that will change a greasemonkey wildcard into a regular expression pattern?

I want to convert `'http://www.google.com/*/index.html'` into `/^http://www.google.com\/\w\/index.html$/`

I want to be able to test the url with a greasmonkey wildchar in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code which converts a `@include/@exclude` to a reg exp is [here](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/master/content/convert2RegExp.js).

All that happens though is that `*` is replaced with `.*` and characters like `[`, `(`, etc are converted to `\[`, `\(`, then the `string` is sent to `new RegExp(string)`.

If you used [Scriptish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scriptish/) then you can use regular expression syntax for the `@include/@exclude`s, like so

```
// @include /^http:\/\/www.google.com\/\w\/index.html$/i
```

Answer (score 3):

Granted I probably haven't exhausted all options of wildcards (nor have I had a huge test database for trials) but here's what I've come up with:

```
String.prototype.toRegExp = function()
{
    var result = this.replace(/([\/\(\)\[\]\.\?])/g,'\\$1');
    result = result.replace('*','.*');
    return new RegExp(result);
}
```

Usage:

```
var re = "http://www.google.com/*".toRegExp();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at [Greasemonkey's source](http://www.mozdev.org/source/browse/greasemonkey/src/chrome/chromeFiles/content/convert2RegExp.js?rev=1.5;content-type=text%2Fplain)

Comment: Pumbaa80, Since this is just a link to an external site, the answer might go *poof* before the next person needs it.  Consider copying the relevant part of that code to your answer.

Comment: the source is on Github btw =]

Comment: @BrockAdams @ErikVold what's the deal with that really long pattern in that function?

Comment: @qwertymk, do you mean the "tld" stuff?  If so, then that is because GM allows you to use things like `@include http://google.tld/` where "tld" will match any "top level domain".  This is useful for scripts on sites like Google that use `.com` for the USA, but use `.de` for Germany, etc.